# Route not using custom method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a route which goes to `/messages/9/reply/` with a custom route in my routes.rb. But the method isn't used nor is he looking for it(REmoving my method doesn't throw an error)

The view, however, IS found. What could cause this?

My route:
`get "/messages/:id/reply/" => "messages#reply", :as => :messages_reply`

Comment: Can you paste relevant controller?

Answer (score 1):

For the given route,

```
get "/messages/:id/reply/" => "messages#reply", :as => :messages_reply
```

An action / method named `reply` in `MessagesController` would be invoked. 
**Make sure that your method name matches to it.**

And if you don't have any explicit call to `render` or `redirect_to` in `reply` method then by default a view named `render.html.***` (where `***` is template handler extension, like erb, haml) from `app/views/messages` directory would be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the whole part of route file which is dedicated to messaging?

I would write this thingie in a more rails way:

```
resources :messages do
    member do
        get :reply
    end
end
```

Assuming that you need REST actions for messages